# Need a mapping between Team name and Area Path in TFS

Tags: sql, rest, tfs

In TFS, Team can be associated with more than one AreaPath. I want to retrieve the mappings between AreaPath and TeamName. Is there any table in TFS databases which has mappings? or any REST API to retrieve that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the [Team field values](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/team-field-values) Rest API.

> The team field is used to identify which work items belong to your
>   team. By default, **Area Path** is the team field, but it can be any
>   field. Use this API to get and set the the team field values.

**Get a team field values**

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/{team}/_apis/Work/TeamSettings/TeamFieldValues?api-version={version}
```

Will return including three area paths:

Default is `Fabrikam-Fiber\\Auto` and `"Fabrikam-Fiber\\Fiber"` and  `"Fabrikam-Fiber\\Optics"`

```
"field": {
    "referenceName": "System.AreaPath",
    "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.AreaPath"
  },
  "defaultValue": "Fabrikam-Fiber\\Auto",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": "Fabrikam-Fiber\\Auto",
      "includeChildren": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Fabrikam-Fiber\\Fiber",
      "includeChildren": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Fabrikam-Fiber\\Optics",
      "includeChildren": false
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your suggestion, but that will not help to get mapping between area path and team name. I already got team name using this API. :(

Comment: If you specify the team name or team ID in the API, won't it return all the field value include System.AreaPath such as `{
  "field": {
    "referenceName": "System.AreaPath",
    "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.AreaPath"
  },`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT area.id, path.[AreaPath],ADObjects_team.SamAccountName, teamproject
 FROM [dbo].[tbl_TeamConfigurationTeamFields]  config 
  inner join [dbo].[ADObjects] ADObjects_team on config.[TeamId]= ADObjects_team.[TeamFoundationId] 
   inner join [dbo].[tbl_ClassificationNode] area  on config.[TeamFieldValue] = area.[Identifier]
   inner join [dbo].[tbl_ClassificationNodePath] path on area.id = path.id
   where arealevel1='Area'    
   order by [AreaPath]
```